# Как на php динамически изменять настройки в файле config.php?

Tags: php

Есть файл config.php примерно такого содержания:

```
<?php
...
$config['param1'] = 'value1';
$config['param2'] = 'value2';
...
```

Как можно красиво динамически перезаписать эти значения? Чтобы можно было например так:

```
$config->setValue('param1','value3');
```

Может есть готовый класс или библиотека для этого? Не хотелось бы изобретать велосипеды.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечу сам. Вариант примерно такой, с учетом того, что доступ к config.txt ограничен на уровне веб сервера.

```
class Config
{
   function __construct() {
       $this->config = unserialize(file_get_contents("config.txt"));
   }

   public function setItem($name, $value) {
       $this->config[$name] = $value;
       file_put_contents('config.txt', serialize($this->config));
       return true;
   }

   public function getItem($name) {
       return $this->config[$name];
   }
}
```

Для вызова

```
$config = new Config;
$config->setItem('itemName', 'itemValue');
...
echo $config->getItem('itemName'); //itemValue
```

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы было вот так например:

```
$config->setValue('param1','value3');
```

Нужно чтобы **config.php** был типом класс, а **setValue** был методом этого класса, который в свою очередь принимает параметры **param1** и **param2**...

Для примера:

```
<?php
class Config(){
   public $param1 = 'value1';
   public $param2 = 'value2';

   public function setValue($param1, $param2) {
        $this->param1 = $param1;
        $this->param2 = $param2;
   }
}
```

Дальше вы можете создать инстанц этого класса, либо указать к нему полный путь, либо использовать **namespase**

Что-то вида:

```
$config = new(/Config);
$config->setValue(true, false);
$param1 = $config->param1;
$param2 = $config->param2;
```

После этого вы можете использовать методы и свойства этого класса как вы хотите! А лучше чтобы вы почитали про ООП, это никогда лишним не будет даже для уже знающего человека о принципах работы.

Всё что написано выше, возможносодержит синтаксические ошибки, и можно использовать как теоретические знания

**Add!**

Если вы хотите, чтобы они сохраняли своё последнее состояние, то создайте файл **.ini**, например, и пишите туда новые значения, а в конструкторе класса, каждый раз используйте **parse_ini_file()** и записывайте в свойства, Ваш вопрос, можно рассмотреть с разных сторон!

Comment: Я с вами полностью согласен про класс, но значения в файле должны перезаписываться, вопрос был как раз об этом.

Comment: @Talleyran Так вы вызывайте метод класса, и перезаписывайте сколько вам нужно раз, а для того чтобы класс был создан только один раз в течение сеанса, прочитайте о **singleton**

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы при изменении массива он писался в файл как в БД. Поэтому я и спрашиваю, есть ли уже готовые проверенные безопасные решения для этой на мой взгляд весьма распространенной задачи? Могу конечно написать file_put_contents("config.txt", serialize($config)) но насколько это правильно?

Comment: @Talleyran А что в этом не безопасного? главное чтобы у файла, хранящего эту информацию, были установленны корректные права по отношению его использования. А также можете и в базе данных хранить, для этого не нужны переменные с конфигами. К тому же вы в БД храните даже пароли людей, по вашему мнению - это не безопасно?! Вы знаете для чего служит файл конфигураций?, уж явно не для хранения динамически изменяющихся данных!

Comment: Под динамикой я подразумевал возможность менять некоторые настройки приложения через web-интерфейс. Приведу в ответе получившийся класс.

Comment: @Talleyran Отлично! Буду надеяться, что мой ответ хоть чем-то был для вас полезным.